# If I have $7$ bills total, how many ways can I give $2$ bills to one person and $3$ bills to a second person?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Title pretty much says it all. I've been struggling to figure out how the combinations would work when you have a remainder of items since we are not using every bill that we have. I know for $n$ groups of m items, we would use $\frac{(mn)!}{m!n!}$ but I'm not quite sure how/if that would carry over to this example.

I know $\binom{7}{3} = 35$.

Do I need to calculate another combination to add the total number of possibilities together?

Edit: The 7 bills are distinct -- 1,2,5,10,20,50,100 not sure how/if that alters the question at all.

Comment: Divide into three groups of 3,2, and 2 using multinomial. $\frac{7!}{3!2!2!}=210$, (Predecide which of the group of 2 to give the first person)

Comment: The title doesn't state the problem unambiguously so please always give a full problem statement (setup and goal) in the body of your Question.   Are the bills identical or distinguishable? Are the first and second persons distinct, so that you want to  combine counting separately giving two bills to the first person and three to the second person with three bills to the first person and two to the second person? Or did you want to exclude the latter outcomes?

Comment: For your last question, the answer in short is "Yes". A longer answer, also as per the below answers, is to calculate the same thing with the remaining bills, and at the end, as each and every outcome of the first assignment can be paired with each and every outcome of the second (as only the remaining bills are used, so any operation is independent of the first operation), "add" actually means "multiply".

Comment: @hardmath That is an interesting approach, I'd think that the question is clear. However, maybe the creator of the question thought the same, so there might be no other info, i.e. this is the full question - but even if that's the case, you could add an answer that covers those scenarios and make the whole thing "round".

Answer (score 1):

You first have to choose $3$ out of the $7$ to give to the first person and you can do that ${7\choose 3}$ ways. Out of the remaining $4$ you have to choose $2$ and you have ${4\choose 2}$ ways to do it.

That way you have ${7\choose 3}{4\choose 2} = 210$ ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first person you have 7 possibilities for the first bill, 6 for the second and you have to divide it by factorial of 2 (order of these two bills is irrelevant). Then for the second person you have 5 possibilities left times 4 times 3 divided by factorial of 3 (order of these three bills is irrelevant). In conclusion
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\frac{7\cdot6}{2!}}_{\text{1st person}} \cdot\underbrace{\frac{5\cdot4\cdot3}{3!}}_{\text{2nd person}}=21\cdot10=210
\end{align}